# Django way to track historical user data

Tags: django

I'm looking to keep track of historical data about users and want to know different opinions or aproaches to do this. I'm trying to do this with as little custom code as possible.

The app needs to save Username and User weight and Height for a given date.
On a second step (wich is not focus of this question), I wil use this data to plot a chart.
The graph will show a day by day weight/height for a given user, to track the evolution of the user.

Until now, I've been working with this simple aproach and want to know if a better way to do this exists.
(this class is just an an example, `IntergerField` to simplify)

```
class ModelExample(model.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
```

In this case, I think the data will be save correctly, but I think it will be a mess to retrieve the information of historical height or weight for a given user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been working with this simple aproach and want to know if a better way to do this exists.

The approach you show is  effective. The only thing I'd add would be a UNIQUE constraint on user & date so you can't get duplicate data for a date (which would screw up your aggregate queries). You can do this using [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class UserDimensionObservation(model.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField() 

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'date',),)
```